# Skip all testthat tests when condition not met

Tags: r, package, devtools, testthat

What is the proper way to skip all tests in the test directory of an R package when using testthat/devtools infrastructure?  For example, if there is no connection to a database and all the tests rely on that connection, do I need to write a `skip` in all the files individually or can I write a single `skip` somewhere?

I have a standard package setup that looks like

> mypackage/
>
> - ...  # other package stuff
> - tests/
>
>   - testthat.R
>   - testthat/
>
>     - test-thing1.R
>     - test-thing2.R

At first I thought I could put a test in the `testthat.R` file like

```
## in testthat.R
library(testthat)
library(mypackage)

fail_test <- function() FALSE
if (fail_test()) test_check("package")
```

but, that didn't work and it looks like calling `devtools::test()` just ignores that file.  I guess an alternative would be to store all the tests in another directory, but is there a better solution?

Comment: In that example, you would need `if( fail_test() )` ...

Answer (score 7):

The [Skipping a test](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) section in the R Packages book covers this use case. Essentially, you write a custom function that checks whatever condition you need to check -- whether or not you can connect to your database -- and then call that function from all tests that require that condition to be satisfied.

Example, parroted from the book:

```r
skip_if_no_db <- function() {
  if (db_conn()) {
    skip("API not available")
  }
}

test_that("foo api returns bar when given baz", {
  skip_if_no_db()
  ...
})
```

I've found this approach more useful than a single switch to toggle off all tests since I tend to have a mix of test that do and don't rely on whatever condition I'm checking and I want to always run as many tests as possible.

Comment: Should you put this in all tests? Is there some way to run it at the "top level" only once?

Comment: Updated link: https://r-pkgs.org/testing-advanced.html#when-testing-gets-hard

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you may organize tests in subdirectories, putting conditional directory inclusion in a parent folder test:

Consider 'tests' in **testthat** package.
In particular, this one looks interesting:

- [test-test_dir.r](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-test_dir.r) that includes *'test_dir'* subdirectory

I do not see here nothing that recurses subdirectories in test scan:

- [**test_dir**](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/master/R/test-files.r#L14)